# What to consider/avoid when having multiple versions of Python installed on Win 10

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I recently discovered that I had multiple versions of Python installed on Windows 10 64 bit (Company PC). To be honest, I didn't realize I had all these version.

So my question is what complications am I imposing when having multiple versions? Also, I only use the Anaconda environment for Python coding, so can I simply remove the stand-alone and 32-bit versions?

Here's what it looks like from my view:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think there'd be a problem? The *reason* to use Anaconda is that it lets you manage this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [similar question in quora forum.](https://www.quora.com/Do-I-still-need-to-install-Python-3-6-for-an-example-even-if-I-installed-Anaconda)

As long as anaconda is a free and open-source distribution of the Python and R you can uninstall other versions. **UPDATE**: Anaconda changed their terms of service in 2020 to prohibit commercial usage in organisations with more than 200 employees.

But there is no need if you don't have problem now. For future use If you want to change environment it's event better to have already installed another.